# how do I find out the bit-endianness of the $BitMap file in NTFS

Tags: endianness, ntfs

Before we get too into this, I'm not at all talking about byte-order-endianness. I'm talking about bit-order-endianness. Do we refer to the "zeroth" bit in a byte as the one that is least significant, (0x01) or the most significant (0x80).

What I would like to confirm is if block zero on an NTFS volume was the only block allocated, would it be represented by a 0x01 in the first byte of the used block bitmap (being  bit little-endian, the zeroth bit is least significant) or 0x80 being bit big-endian, the zero bit is the most significant)

It's really hard to find information on this because is it such a rare topic, but I remember parsing an hfs+ used block bitmap years ago and I remember it being the opposite of ntfs, whereas ntfs I believe is bit little-endian and hfs+ was bit big-endian.

can anybody confirm which way it is in ntfs?